# Click Once - CD Deployment doesn't Update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce, updates

I am deploying a WPF application using ClickOnce

Initial deployments are planned via CD/DVD so that user can quickly install all the prerequisites and the application, but along with that an website update location is provided so that whenever an update is released, users would be able to install it.

But the issue we are facing is although we increment the build version and deploy the application on webserver, none of the user identifies there is an update and just runs the initial version.

I follow the steps exactly as described in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400068/can-i-deploy-a-clickonce-application-via-cd-and-update-via-web)

Following is what I do:

**1. First version (for e.g. 1.0.0.1) is deployed in a CD and installed on a computer.**

*Publish Location*

- Publish Folder Location is `Path of the CD Drive`
- Install Folder URL is `empty`. (Because it will installed from CD itself)

*Under updates*

- The application should check for updates is `True` and `Before the application starts`
- Update location is website : `www.xxxxx.com/ApplicationFolder/`

*Options*

- For CD installations, automatically start Setup when CD is inserted is `Checked`

**2. Second version (for e.g. 1.0.0.2) is deployed on web**

*Publish Location*

- Publish Folder Location is `ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx/httpdocs/ApplicationFolder/` (same as update location in CD installation, but via ftp. I have to use FTP here because FrontPage server extension is not installed on my web server.)
- Install Folder URL is ``www.xxxxx.com/ApplicationFolder/` (same as the path of update location in CD installation)

*Updates*

- The application should check for updates is `True` and `Before the application starts`
- Update location is `empty`.

*Options*

- For CD installations, automatically start Setup when CD is inserted is `Unchecked`

Why doesn't it recognize any update ? Is there a file where in we can verify the update location ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the Update location on the second version. That should fix your problem.